# FATAL when switching from test network to public network on stellar-core

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, testnet, postgres

My question is about transitioning from the test-network to the public network. I am curious about whether there is a standard procedure to follow, not only in terms of configuration, but also in terms of resetting databases and clearing out buckets, logs, etc.

**Here is a more detailed description of my issue:**
I finally built Horizon and Stellar-core from source on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and successfully configured both for the test network. Since both instances were up and running on the test network yesterday, I decided to go to the next level and configure them for the public network today.

To switch to the public network, the `stellar-core.cfg`, or in other words the Stellar TOML file, has to be edited. One particularly important option is the `NETWORK_PHRASE`. The value for this option should be set to:

`NETWORK_PHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"`

when connecting to the public network, and:

`NETWORK_PHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"`

when connecting to the test network. The same holds for the `horizon.env` file, which is Horizon's equivalent configuration file.

In addition to the above alterations to the stellar-core TOML file, specifying whether the stellar-core instance will be a validator, in addition to PEERS and QUORUM SET must be defined. In this case, these are unrelated to my issue, or at least so I suspect.

When I decided to start stellar core with a new configuration file specified for the public network with the following command:

`$ stellar-core --conf public-config.cfg`

My log provided the following:

`GDMPG [default FATAL] Got an exception: NETWORK_PASSPHRASE "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015" does not match previous NETWORK_PASSPHRASE "Test SDF Network ; September 2015" [main.cpp:671]`

I have tried to source the new configuration file and start without the `--conf` option, but at that point I am unable to connect to the Overlay.

What is the correct approach to solving this problem? Should I restart PostgreSQL, or is there an issue related to `public-config.cfg`? Are there some files generated from running the test-network instance that I have to delete? And if so, which files should I delete? I was skeptical towards these latter aspects since I tried deleting files manually before which made me have to re-build stellar-core from scratch again.

Many thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

After re-configuring the `stellar-core.cfg` file, and creating a custom Quorum set, I keep experiencing problems with the Work and Overlay components, but I am no longer getting the above `FATAL` error.

It appears to be that my Stellar-core instance does not catch up / sync appropriately as it cannot retrieve `get-remote-file history/01/1a/09/history-011a09ff.json`.

Indeed, when I run Horizon, I am informed of:

`WARN[0256] ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync         pid=12899`

Usually, this error would arise due to an erroneously specified History Archive. Yet, I have also run `stellar-core --newhist ARCH` and checked that the directories are in place.

Interestingly enough, the directories are made in rather counter-intuitive ways, but they still appear to be configured correctly according to the stellar-core `INFO`.

Given this exhaustive information, I am suspicious regarding whether the reason why I am unable to sync onto the Public network is because I have to be approved by other nodes. Is this correct?

**EDIT 2**
So, now I have updated the buckets directory by making a new directory called public-buckets, and re-initialized the database.

Also tried editing the `KNOWN_PEERS` section in config file. I understood the problem lies in the configuration after reviewing `OverylayManagerImpl.cpp` on:
https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/overlay/OverlayManagerImpl.cpp

Will update once I get it working :) 
`

Comment: `stellar-core --newdb` should help.

Comment: Keep getting the same error unfortunately, even after running the `--newdb` command.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to switch between networks is to not reuse directories and/or archives (unless you can guarantee that you can delete all data). This particular error `... does not match previous NETWORK_PASSPHRASE ...` will be cleared after running `newdb` as that command drops all tables in the database.

As for your later question, there is no vetting process to join the network: anybody can watch the network, and once you have a node up and running you can ask other people to trust your validator but this is a different problem.

Comment: Thanks @MonsieurNicolas. Good to know approval is not required, because then it simply means that the issue lies in the configuration.

As the first problem is overcome, I suspect that a major part of the problem comes from the way the history archives are specified. I will post an edit for this.