# How to quickstart to pubnet while install SDF package

Tags: stellar-core

I had check previous question [switch from testnet to pubnet](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/fatal-when-switching-from-test-network-to-public-network-on-stellar-core/2675#2675), However, the answer is not helpful.

I had installed stellar SDF package three times and switching pubnet after successfully install.

How can I start it to pubnet or switch to testnet？

If I modify stellar-core.cfg to pubnet, I always got the following FATAL

```
2019-07-22T08:14:40.011 GDE6V [default FATAL] Please report this bug along with this log file if this was not expected [ApplicationUtils.cpp:68]
2019-07-22T08:14:40.258 GAW7F [default INFO] Starting stellar-core stellar-core 11.2.0 (f3857733a9b67da4528df59bb616ea84ba539a1a)
2019-07-22T08:14:40.261 GAW7F [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=stellar user=stellar
2019-07-22T08:14:40.264 GAW7F [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GAW7F qSet: e57c2e
2019-07-22T08:14:40.264 GAW7F [default INFO] Listening on 127.0.0.1:11626 for HTTP requests
2019-07-22T08:14:40.265 GAW7F [Database INFO] DB schema is in current version
2019-07-22T08:14:40.265 GAW7F [default INFO] Application destructing
2019-07-22T08:14:40.266 GAW7F [default INFO] Application destroyed
2019-07-22T08:14:40.266 GAW7F [default FATAL] Got an exception: NETWORK_PASSPHRASE "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015" does not match previous NETWORK_PASSPHRASE "Test SDF Network ; September 2015" [ApplicationUtils.cpp:67]
```

Comment: Can you add more details about why the other answer was not helpful?

Comment: I post what happen as following,  This comment has word limitation.

Answer (score 1):

[@yi-ru-chen](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/2388/yi-ru-chen) - The solution is in the previous answer you linked to 
[switching-from-testnet-to-pubnet](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/fatal-when-switching-from-test-network-to-public-network-on-stellar-core/2675#2675), given by [@monsieurnicolas](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/58/monsieurnicolas).

You need to delete the database used while connected to the testnet and ready it for connecting to the pubet. Run:

```
$ /usr/bin/stellar-core --conf /etc/stellar/stellar-core.cfg new-db
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed SDF package from https://github.com/stellar/packages.git

I did the following step by qickstart

```
apt-get install stellar-quickstart
```

it will start in TESTNET automatically.

Then, I change stellar-core.cfg as following

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
LOG_FILE_PATH=""

DATABASE="postgresql://...."
NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"
CATCHUP_RECENT=8640

NODE_SEED="SBxxxxxxxxxx3"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

NODE_NAMES=[
"GAOO3LWBC4XF6VWRP5ESJ6IBHAISVJMSBTALHOQM2EZG7Q477UWA6L7U  eno",
"GAXP5DW4CVCW2BJNPFGTWCEGZTJKTNWFQQBE5SCWNJIJ54BOHR3WQC3W  moni",
"GBFZFQRGOPQC5OEAWO76NOY6LBRLUNH4I5QYPUYAK53QSQWVTQ2D4FT5  dzham",
"GDXWQCSKVYAJSUGR2HBYVFVR7NA7YWYSYK3XYKKFO553OQGOHAUP2PX2  jianing",
"GCJCSMSPIWKKPR7WEPIQG63PDF7JGGEENRC33OKVBSPUDIRL6ZZ5M7OO  tempo.eu.com",
"GCCW4H2DKAC7YYW62H3ZBDRRE5KXRLYLI4T5QOSO6EAMUOE37ICSKKRJ  sparrow_tw",
"GD5DJQDDBKGAYNEAXU562HYGOOSYAEOO6AS53PZXBOZGCP5M2OPGMZV3  fuxi.lab",
"GBGGNBZVYNMVLCWNQRO7ASU6XX2MRPITAGLASRWOWLB4ZIIPHMGNMC4I  huang.lab",
"GDPJ4DPPFEIP2YTSQNOKT7NMLPKU2FFVOEIJMG36RCMBWBUR4GTXLL57  nezha.lab",
"GCDLFPQ76D6YUSCUECLKI3AFEVXFWVRY2RZH2YQNYII35FDECWUGV24T  SnT.Lux",
"GBAR4OY6T6M4P344IF5II5DNWHVUJU7OLQPSMG2FWVJAFF642BX5E3GB  telindus",
"GBJQUIXUO4XSNPAUT6ODLZUJRV2NPXYASKUBY4G5MYP3M47PCVI55MNT  SatoshiPay",
# non validating
"GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1",
"GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2",
"GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3",
# seem down
"GB6REF5GOGGSEHZ3L2YK6K4T4KX3YDMWHDCPMV7MZJDLHBDNZXEPRBGM  donovan",
"GBGR22MRCIVW2UZHFXMY5UIBJGPYABPQXQ5GGMNCSUM2KHE3N6CNH6G5  nelisky1",
"GA2DE5AQF32LU5OZ5OKAFGPA2DLW4H6JHPGYJUVTNS3W7N2YZCTQFFV6  nelisky2",
"GDJ73EX25GGUVMUBCK6DPSTJLYP3IC7I3H2URLXJQ5YP56BW756OUHIG  w00kie",
"GAM7A32QZF5PJASRSGVFPAB36WWTHCBHO5CHG3WUFTUQPT7NZX3ONJU4  ptarasov"
]

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-live-a.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-b.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-c.stellar.org:11625",
"confucius.strllar.org",
"stellar1.bitventure.co",
"stellar.256kw.com",
"stellar-sg-sin.satoshipay.io:11625"
]

[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=[
"$sdf_watcher1","$eno","$tempo.eu.com","$sdf_watcher2","$sdf_watcher3"
]

[HISTORY.cache]
get="cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/{0} {1}"

# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.sdf1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Then, I got error "Got an exception: NETWORK_PASSPHRASE "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015" does not match previous NETWORK_PASSPHRASE "Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

Because I switched from TESTNET to PUBNET.

So, How to switch PUBNET?  Which file I need to delete or reset?

thanks